# Really confused

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, p-vs-np

Suppose there is a language L∈NP, that is not NP-Complete and L≠∅ and L≠Σ∗. Which of the following statements can we infer from this?

P = NP

P ⊊ NP

P ≠ NP

NP ⊆ P

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142937/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68662236/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if $P=NP$? Clearly $P$-complete $=P$, and hence also $NP$-complete = $NP$. This means that every language in $NP$ would also be in $NP$-complete. So finding a language that *isn't* $NP$-complete, means that we must have $P\neq NP$